# I can not show the saved images in the database

Tags: django, django-forms

I am not able to show the images saved in the database, all other data appears, the only problem is in the images, in the html put the 3 commanders I tried to load the images.
I am very beginner in python and django any help would be very welcome
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

models.py:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
     foto = models.ImageField( blank=False, verbose_name="Foto para seu perfil", upload_to='sistema/img')
```

settings.py:

```
    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '$n+6cd+9w+44=z*0o=8b#t&9*i!_ay%&6+kl=_cbq0%*sm0)c('

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.127.0.0.1',]



    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'sistema',
        'PetAqui',
        'bootstrapform',
        'widget_tweaks',
        'crispy_forms',
        'multiselectfield',
    'django.contrib.sites',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_auth',
        'rest_auth.registration',
        'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',


    ]

    SITE_ID=1

    CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'PetAqui.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },

    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'PetAqui.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'petaqui',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'gt1utff7st3re',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')



    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

    )



    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'estacioneaqui24@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '10038561003856'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587


    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'sistema_index'
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'sistema_index'
    LOGIN_URL = 'sistema_index'

    MEDIA_ROOT='/sistema/img/'
    MEDIA_URL='/img/'
```

html:

```
    <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{ user.usuario.foto }}" >
        {{ user.usuario.foto  }}
        {{ user.usuario.foto.url  }}
```

urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.urls import include, path
    from . import views

    from .views import (
        index,
        cadastro,
        cadastro_novo,
        cadastro_negocio,
        activate,
        account_activation_sent,
        perfil

    )

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^index/$', index, name='sistema_index'),
        url(r'^cadastro/$', cadastro, name='sistema_cadastro'),
        url(r'perfil/$', perfil, name='sistema_perfil'),
        url(r'^cadastro-novo/$', cadastro_novo, name='sistema_cadastro_novo'),
        url(r'^cadastro-negocio/$', cadastro_negocio, name='sistema_cadastro_negocio'),
        url(r'^account_activation_sent/$', views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
        path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),


    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: check on your computer where the image is uploaded (in which directory relative to your project root). Then check in your browser developer tools the source of your HTML, what's the img path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
<img src="{{ user.usuario.foto.url }}" />
```

If that doesn't work, then include your urls.py file, what url you're browsing to and what response is returned.

Comment: I edited and put my urls, did not work your suggestion, I must be making a stupid mistake

Comment: I think you need to add the media files to your urls.py file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: I made the changes according to the documentation and even then it does not appear